# When deleting uploaded images, it trigger the store button instead

Tags: php, laravel

Uploading the images has no problem but when deleting the uploaded images, it triggers the store button instead. I am wondering why is this happening?

Controller code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required|max:150',
            'category_id' => 'required',
            'type_id' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required|numeric|min:0|not_in:0',
            'start_date' => 'required',
            'end_date' => 'required',
            'is_active' => 'required',
            'images.*' => 'image|max:2048', // max file size: 2MB
            'documents.*' => 'file|max:2048', // max file size: 2MB
        ]);

        $product = DB::table('products')
            ->insertGetId([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'description' => $data['description'],
                'type_id' => $data['type_id'],
                'category_id' => $data['category_id'],
                'price' => $data['price'],
                'start_date' => $data['start_date'],
                'end_date' => $data['end_date'],
                'is_password' => $request['is_password'],
                'is_stamping' => $request['is_stamping'],
                'created_at' => now(),
            ]);

        // handle image uploads
        if ($request->hasFile('images')) {
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($request->file('images') as $image) {
                $name = $request['name'] . '-' . $i;
                $now = new DateTime();
                $fileName = Str::slug($request['name']) . '-' . $now->format('dmYHis') . '-' . $i . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                //$fileName = Str::slug($request['name']) . '-' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $path = $image->storeAs('public/Product/Images', $fileName);
                DB::table('product_images')->insert([
                    'product_id' => $product,
                    'name' => $name,
                    'file_path' => Storage::url($path),
                    'created_at' => now(),
                ]);
                $i++;
            }
        }
}
        return Redirect::route('produk.index');
    }

public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $data = $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required|max:150',
            'category_id' => 'required',
            'type_id' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required|numeric|min:0|not_in:0',
            'start_date' => 'required',
            'end_date' => 'required',
            'is_active' => 'required',
            'images.*' => 'image|max:2048', // max file size: 2MB
            'documents.*' => 'file|max:2048', // max file size: 2MB
        ]);

        DB::table('products')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->update([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'description' => $data['description'],
                'type_id' => $data['type_id'],
                'category_id' => $data['category_id'],
                'price' => $data['price'],
                'start_date' => $data['start_date'],
                'end_date' => $data['end_date'],
                'is_active' => $data['is_active'],
                'is_password' => $request['is_password'],
                'is_stamping' => $request['is_stamping'],
                'updated_at' => now(),
            ]);

        // handle image uploads
        if ($request->hasFile('images')) {
            //DB::table('product_images')->where('product_id', $id)->delete();
            //Storage::deleteDirectory('public/Product/Images/' . $id);
            foreach ($request->file('images') as $image) {
                $name = $request['name'] . '-' . $id;
                $now = new DateTime();
                $fileName = Str::slug($request['name']) . '-' . $now->format('dmYHis') . '-' . $id . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $path = $image->store('public/Product/Images/' . $fileName);
                DB::table('product_images')->insert([
                    'product_id' => $id,
                    'file_path' => Storage::url($path),
                    'created_at' => now(),
                ]);
            }
        }
return Redirect::route('produk.index');
    }
```

The button that gets triggered,

```
const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            name: action === "create" ? "" : `${data.name}`,
            description: action === "create" ? "" : `${data.description}`,
            category_id: action === "create" ? "" : `${data.category_id}`,
            type_id: action === "create" ? "" : `${data.type_id}`,
            price: action === "create" ? "" : `${data.price}`,
            is_active: action === "create" ? "" : `${data.is_active}`,
            start_date: action === "create" ? "" : `${data.start_date}`,
            end_date: action === "create" ? "" : `${data.end_date}`,
            // is_password: action === "create" ? "" : `${data.is_password}`,
            // is_stamping: action === "create" ? "" : `${data.is_stamping}`,
        },
        validationSchema: validationSchema,

        onSubmit: async (values) => {
            try {
                switch (action) {
                    case "create":
                        await post(route("produk.store"));
                        Swal.fire({
                            text: "Maklumat produk berjaya disimpan",
                            icon: "success",
                        });
                        break;
                    case "update":
                        await put(route("produk.update", product.id), data);
                        Swal.fire({
                            text: "Maklumat produk berjaya dikemaskini",
                            icon: "success",
                        });
                        break;
                }
            } catch (error) {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: "error",
                    title: "Oops...",
                    text: "Something went wrong!",
                });
            }
        },
    });

    return (
        <form method={"post"} onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>

                        ....................
```

Delete button to remove file upload when adding product

```
{/* Delete button to remove file upload when adding product */}
    const removeFileUpload = (e, index) => {
        const updatedFileUpload = [...fileUpload];
        updatedFileUpload.splice(index, 1);
        setFileUpload(updatedFileUpload);
        setData(name, updatedFileUpload);
    };
```

Delete button to remove img when editing/updating product

```
return (
                   ...........
                    
{/* Delete Button when editing/update */}
        <button
           onClick={() => removeFileUpload(index)}
           className="outline-none border-none"
         >
           <FaTimes className="text-red-600" />
        </button>
.....
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful to either tag whatever templating engine you're using to create the page, or just provide the rendered HTML and JS. Obviously what you've provided here is neither valid HTML or Javascript. And you are not setting the request method to "DELETE" anywhere that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason could be that the button is within the form element, which triggers the form submit. You should add

```
event.preventDefault();
```

to the event listener of the delete handler , so it doesn't bubbles the event to top elements or you could move the delete button out side the form tag

Comment: i've found the delete button code, have a loon on this page. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75911240/when-deleting-uploaded-images-it-trigger-the-store-button-instead-of-performing`

Comment: have you tried adding the code inside the function removeFileUpload add this code e.preventDefault(); before this line const updatedFileUpload = [...fileUpload];   and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I have to create a new function when clicking the button as such,

```
/* Delete documents button when updating/editing form*/
    const removeFileUpload2 = async (type) => {
        console.log(" ~ removeFileUpload2 ~ type:", type);
        try {
            const fileType = type.file_path.endsWith(".pdf")
                ? "document"
                : "image";
            const routeName =
                fileType === "document"
                    ? "product-documents.destroy"
                    : "product-images.destroy";
            await Inertia.delete(route(routeName, type));
            Swal.fire(
                "Berjaya!",
                `Rekod jenis ${fileType} berjaya dipadam.`,
                "success"
            );
        } catch (error) {
            Swal.fire("Ralat!", error.response.data.message, "error");
        }
    }
```

And then use it on the button,

```
    <span
         onClick={() => removeFileUpload2(file)}
         className="outline-none border-none cursor-pointer"
    >
         <FaTimes className="text-red-600" />
    </span>
```